# Adding more than four params in Assembly

Tags: c++, assembly, masm

I have C++ file and .asm file as shown below.Am trying to add all params i passed in summation function

```
summation(int a ,int b ,int c ,int d, int e,int f)
```

c++ file looks like this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

extern "C" int summation(int a ,int b ,int c ,int d, int e,int f);


int main(){

cout << "Summation : "<<summation(1,2,7,1,8,10)<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

And asm file looks like this :

```
.code

summation proc

    sub rsp,30h
    mov eax,ecx
    add eax,edx
    add eax,r8d
    add eax,r9d

    add eax,dword ptr [rsp+20h]
    add eax,dword ptr [rsp+28h]
    add rsp,30h
    ret 
summation endp

end
```

Having those code the result is always 22 (It should be 29). What's wrong with my code ?

Comment: You're using fastcall, it won't handle more than 4. The rest is pushed on the stack for you.

Comment: so how can i handle them (those pushed onto stack)? @ScarletAmaranth

Comment: Why don't you just let a 64-bit C compiler tell you the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to preserve space for your stack frame unless you are doing a [calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) , fast call only allows 4 params , try using the stack directly using the RSP ,

```
summation proc

    mov eax,ecx
    add eax,edx
    add eax,ebx
    add eax,r8d
    add eax,r9d

    add eax,[rsp+50o]
    add eax,[rsp+60o]


    ret
summation endp
```

I used octadecimal you can use decimal if you prefer

Answer (score 2):

rsp+20h doesn't point at the parameter area. You yourself subtract 30h from rsp in the beginning, not sure why - why do you expect pushed parameters to be within that area? They're below the frame.

To recap: on procedure entrance, the return address takes 8 bytes at rsp. Below that, there are the two pushed parameters - at rsp+8 and rsp+0ch. If you decrease rsp by 30h more, they're at rsp+38h, rsc+3ch.

Comment: yah I made mistake..From what i wrote "dword ptr [rsp+20h]"and "dword ptr [rsp+20h]" can't hold the rest two numbers.But i don't know how to push them to the stack..if you found a solution can you please write the whole version of my asm file..@Seva Alekseyev

Comment: The C code pushes them to the stack while performing a call. The assembly procedure just needs to know where on the stack to find them.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with your  [stack Frame](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Functions_and_Stack_Frames) you need to fix it first :)
but I have a solution for you , try this one

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
extern "C" int sum2(int *i,int a);  
int main()
{
int i2[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,10,20,30,40,50};
cout << "The Sum is using Array : "<< sum2 (i2,10)<<endl;
_getch();
return 0;
}
```

in your asm.asm put this

```
sum2 proc

;{1,2,3,4,5,10,20,30,40,50}; //165
mov rax,0 ;Initialize it to zero 
mov rbx,rdx

adding:
add rax,[rcx]
add rcx,4
dec rbx
jnz adding;

finish: 
    ret

sum2 endp
```

it also sums the numbers , but this time from an array 
hope it helps